# Getting corresponding coordinates of a vectorized matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, matrix

I have a matrix **X** of size `n x m`. I resized **X** to a vector **a** of length `n x m`.

How can I know "automatically" that the `ith` element in vector **a** corresponds to what element position (coordinates) in **X**?

I have written the following MATLAB code but I do not know how to continue.

```
X = rand(10,10);
[n,m] = size(X);
a = reshape(X, [n*m, 1]);
t = zeros(length(a),1);

for i = 1 : length(a)
    t(i) = % I want to perform here the sum over the x and y coordinate values of the element in X 
             % that corresponds to the ith element in vector a.
end
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) does:

```
[row, col] = ind2sub([m n], i);
```

However, you may prefer to do it manually:

```
row = mod(i-1,m)+1;
col = floor((i-1)/m)+1;
```

This works because Matlab used [column-major order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/what-are-column-major-and-row-major-representation-1.html) for storing array elements. For example, in a 3×4 matrix the order in which the elements are stored in memory is as follows:

```
 1     4     7    10
 2     5     8    11
 3     6     9    12
```

So the entry in the 2nd row, 3rd column is the 8th element in (column-major) linear order. When this matrix is reshaped into a vector (or into any other shape) this linear order is preserved. Therefore you can retrieve the original coordinates by divisions and modulus operations. Note also that, since Matlab's indexing is 1-based (as opposed to 0-based), the modulus operations need to be shifted by 1.

Comment: How did you think mathematically in order to do it manually?

Comment: I just included an explanation at the end of my answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Do you think that col should be floor(i-1,m)+1 ?

Comment: @Christina Indeed! Sorry for the mistake. I have corrected it in the answer

Comment: Hello again! I asked a new question which continues your answer here. I am looking for your help! Thank you! My new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202530/corresponding-coordinates-of-a-vectorized-matrix-in-python

Comment: @Christina I can't be of much help with Numpy, but it looks like you already got an answer

Comment: Don't worry yes I think I have to swap the order in Python as mentioned in the answer. Thank you a lot anyway!