# Corresponding coordinates of a vectorized matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I had already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043946/getting-corresponding-coordinates-of-a-vectorized-matrix/65044036?noredirect=1#comment115115313_65044036) of how to get using Matlab the corresponding coordinates of a vectorized matrix.

I am wondering how can the answer be changed to Python. Does Python apply the same concept of storing the array elements but instead of starting by 1, it starts by 0?

By applying the same array elements storing as mentioned in the answer, and by performing `sub2ind` manually in Python, I am doing:

```
row = np.mod(i,m)
col = np.floor((i)/m)
```

Am I correct? Looking for someone who can provide me more details in case I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays are stored in row-major order so you would need

```
col = np.mod(i,m)
row = np.floor((i)/m)
```

which can be written simpler as

```
col = i%m
row = i//m
```

However, numpy has the `numpy.unravel_index` function which does this without the need for manual computations.

Comment: Great! Thank you much.